# Proxying S3 bucket with nginx, running on ec2 instance

Tags: angularjs, nginx, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I've been looking through different posts, but no luck so far. Let me describe the overal flow I want to achieve. As an input there is an ec2 instance and two s3 buckets. I need to configure nginx proxy on this ec2 instance to make it possible for users to communicate with s3 storages where angularjs clients reside. For example, having request below:

```
GET: http://my-ec2-instance.compute.amazonaws.com/first-app/index.html
```

I want nginx to pass it to the application hosted in first bucket, and retrieve response as if I'd made request directly to

```
http://first-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com
```

My bucket policy is as follow:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "AddPerm",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": "s3:GetObject",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::first-bucket/*"
    }
]
}
```

and static web hosting enabled. I can even access my index page directly, like:

```
http://first-bucket.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/
```

In addition I made index.html and client side folders containing html, js and css public. Folder hierarchy in s3 storage is:

```
 first-app\
          |- index.html
          |- app\
                |- app.js
                |- css
                |- partials
                |- vendor
```

Here is server configuration section from my nginx.conf:

```
server {
    location /first-app/ {
        try_files $uri @s3-first-bucket;
    }

    location /second-app/ {
        try_files $uri @s3-second-bucket;
    }

    location @s3-first-bucket {

        set $s3_bucket        'first-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com';
        set $url_full         '$1';

        proxy_http_version     1.1;
        proxy_set_header       Host $s3_bucket;
        proxy_set_header       Authorization '';
        proxy_hide_header      x-amz-id-2;
        proxy_hide_header      x-amz-request-id;
        proxy_hide_header      Set-Cookie;
        proxy_ignore_headers   "Set-Cookie";
        proxy_buffering        off;
        proxy_intercept_errors on;

        resolver               8.8.4.4 8.8.8.8 valid=300s;
        resolver_timeout       10s;
        proxy_pass             http://$s3_bucket/$url_full;
    }

    location @s3-second-bucket {

        set $s3_bucket        'second-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com';
        set $url_full         '$1';

        proxy_http_version     1.1;
        proxy_set_header       Host $s3_bucket;
        proxy_set_header       Authorization '';
        proxy_hide_header      x-amz-id-2;
        proxy_hide_header      x-amz-request-id;
        proxy_hide_header      Set-Cookie;
        proxy_ignore_headers   "Set-Cookie";
        proxy_buffering        off;
        proxy_intercept_errors on;

        resolver               8.8.4.4 8.8.8.8 valid=300s;
        resolver_timeout       10s;
        proxy_pass             http://$s3_bucket/$url_full;
    }
}
```

Comment: @were you able to get this working?